# how to make a unordered list nav mobile friendly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the navigation on my site responsive (and ultimately mobile friendly), but I can't get it to work the way I want to.

Ideally, the logo would be on top and the other nav links would be stacked (one per line) below on screens less than 480px, but I'll settle for anything that is legible on a mobile screen for now.

I've looked into a lot of different responsive options, but nothing seems to work for how my nav is set-up.

The site is live here: http://prettylushrecords.com/

Relevant HTML:

```
<body>
    <ul id="navmenu">
        <li><a href="http://prettylushrecords.storenvy.com/">STORE</a></li>
        <li><a href="bands">BANDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="releases.html">RELEASES</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#navmenu {
    background: url(http://prettylushrecords.comoj.com/prettylushlogosmall.png) no-repeat center top;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    }

li, li + li + li + li {
    display: block; 
    float: left;
    height: 220x;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em 1%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 18%;
    }

li + li + li {
    margin-left: 20%;
    padding: .5em 0;
    }

li {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 220px;
    font-family: Courier, monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #bdb0b0;
    }

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

#navmenu {
    background: url(http://prettylushrecords.comoj.com/prettylushlogosmall.png) no-repeat center top;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    }

li {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-family: Courier, monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #bdb0b0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and try this http://tinynav.viljamis.com/

This is what it does

> ....converts  and  navigations to a select dropdowns for small
>   screen. It also automatically selects the current page and adds
>   selected="selected" for that item.

Answer (score 0):

I really would suggest structuring your html tags a in a cleaner way.

```
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li>asdfad</li>
   <li><div><img src="yourimage"/></div></li>
   <li>asdf</li>
   <li>asdf</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

css

DO NOT DO THIS li + li + li( you just need one li to style all lis and look at css selectors)
try this:

```
  li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 220x;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em 1%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 18%;
    }

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
float: none;
line-height: 5px;
}
```

try to look at w3 specs and other websites how they setup header.
Always using inspect element on how they setup and their css, it will help you.

GL

Comment: Thank you for your advice @ravitadi. I tried to clean up the code, but am now having trouble with the nav being centered horizontally and stretching full width. It just sits in the upper left corner now. Here is a fiddle to illustrate: jsfiddle.net/gB7td Any thoughts?